# Move a div horizontally with mouse using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to move a div horizontally on mouse moving. Here's my code so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#test {
   width: 300px;
   height: 60px;
   background-color: #333;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 20px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#test').bind('mousedown', function (e) {
    $(document).bind('mousemove', function (e) {
        var diff = e.pageX - $('#test').offset().left;
        $('#test').css('left', diff + 'px');
    });
});

$(window).bind('mouseup', function (e) {
    $(document).unbind('mousemove');
});

});
```

Div actually moves, but in a strange way. https://jsfiddle.net/ktLskwos/1/
How can I make it work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/ktLskwos/5/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').on('mousedown', function (e) {
        $this = $(this);
        $(document).bind('mousemove', function (e) {
            var left = e.pageX - ($this.width()/2);
            var top = e.pageY - ($this.height()/2);
            $('#test').css({
                'left': left + 'px',
                'top': top + 'px'
            });
        });
    });
    $(window).on('mouseup', function (e) {
        $(document).unbind('mousemove');
    });
});
```

```css
#test {
    width: 300px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #333;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: I removed 'top': e.pageY and its exactly what I need. Thanks

Comment: @dchatzis is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted, but now I got another issue. I added some images inside the moving div and now it doesn't move like before. https://jsfiddle.net/bj0n7Lnv/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you add only the diffrence? You need to add the diffrence relative to position. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ktLskwos/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').bind('mousedown', function (e) {
        $(document).bind('mousemove', function (e) {
            var diff = e.pageX - $('#test').offset().left;
            $('#test').css('left', (diff+$('#test').offset().left) + 'px'); 
            //You need to remove it the mouse offset plus the diffrence, not to the diffrence between the previous position and the offset-
            // that'd just leave you rotating left and right between the position you want and the negative,
            // Since the diffrence changes each time you move on mousedown
        });
    });

    $(window).bind('mouseup', function (e) {
        $(document).unbind('mousemove');
    });
});
```

Comment: When I move it, the cursor goes at the beginning of the div. Can it stay where I clicked and move the div?

Comment: @dchatzis That'd be what Rejith did.